# how to make a "point" in VTK larger/thicker/spherelike

Tags: vtk

I have approx 1 million datapoints representing the x,y,z,t coordinates of a number of small balls. I'm trying to create a system to view how they change over time.

I am trying to make a 3D plot.

if I plot the balls as "points" in VTK I find that they can be rendered pretty quickly. However, in the ideal scenario, I would be using tiny spheres to represent the data points.

I am concerned that 1M spheres would take too long to render. So I am wondering if there is some way to use the vtkpoints class but to 1.) look circular (instead of rectangular) and 2.) force them to appear bigger on the screen when I zoom in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. 1) is possible through the `vtkPlotPoints` class. 2) is possible through the `SetWidth` method.

Here is a runnable script to enlighten better, with other functionalities you may find useful:

```
import vtk
import math

view = vtk.vtkContextView()
view.GetRenderer().SetBackground(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
view.GetRenderWindow().SetSize(400, 300)

chart = vtk.vtkChartXY()
view.GetScene().AddItem(chart)
chart.SetShowLegend(True)

table = vtk.vtkTable()

arrX = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
arrX.SetName('X Axis')

arrC = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
arrC.SetName('Cosine')

arrS = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
arrS.SetName('Sine')

arrT = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
arrT.SetName('Sine-Cosine')

table.AddColumn(arrC)
table.AddColumn(arrS)
table.AddColumn(arrX)
table.AddColumn(arrT)

numPoints = 40

inc = 7.5/(numPoints-1)
table.SetNumberOfRows(numPoints)
for i in range(numPoints):
    table.SetValue(i, 0, i*inc)
    table.SetValue(i, 1, math.cos(i*inc))
    table.SetValue(i, 2, math.sin(i*inc))
    table.SetValue(i, 3, math.sin(i*inc)-math.cos(i*inc))

points = chart.AddPlot(vtk.vtkChart.POINTS) 
points.SetInput(table, 0, 1)
points.SetColor(0, 0, 0, 255)
points.SetWidth(4.0)
points.SetMarkerStyle(vtk.vtkPlotPoints.DIAMOND) #CROSS, SQUARE, CIRCLE... 

points = chart.AddPlot(vtk.vtkChart.POINTS)
points.SetInput(table, 0, 2)
points.SetColor(0, 0, 0, 255)
points.SetWidth(1.0)
points.SetMarkerStyle(vtk.vtkPlotPoints.PLUS)

points = chart.AddPlot(vtk.vtkChart.POINTS)
points.SetInput(table, 0, 3)
points.SetColor(0, 0, 255, 255)
points.SetWidth(1.0)
points.SetMarkerStyle(vtk.vtkPlotPoints.CIRCLE)

view.GetRenderWindow().SetMultiSamples(0)
view.GetInteractor().Initialize()
view.GetInteractor().Start()
```

Hope this helps!